# jetty not accessible using internal ip address(192.168.1.134) but works with localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: embedded-jetty

I am trying to run embadded jetty using eclipse. below is the code snippet.

```
Server server = new Server(4269);
ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/abc");
server.start();
server.join();
```

I can see following in console when I run.

```
2015-09-12 10:52:41.360:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2015-09-12 10:52:41.402:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started    SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4269
```

so its listening to 0.0.0.0:4269. I expect it to be accessible using localhost:4269/abc, 127.0.0.1:4269/abc and 192.168.1.134:4269/abc. However, it doesn't work with 192.168.1.134:4269/abc and even with my static ip http://10.xxx.xx.xx:4269/abc.

Please guide me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) now, you are *strongly encouraged* to upgrade.

The output you see ...

```
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4269
```

Says that the Java bound to the [non-routable meta-address `0.0.0.0` for all local IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), which means it bound to all of your available network interfaces.

Things to look for:

- Does that interface exist?
- Is that interface up and connected with a valid IP?
- [Can Java see that interface?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)
- Does your netstat command (or equivalent on your OS) report that something is bound to interface `192.168.1.134'?
- Are Firewall rules preventing access?
- Is there network security rules that might be preventing access? (SELinux)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue was with interface ip address which got changed due to it was mentioned as dhcp. I added manual ip address and it started working